# ¿Cómo agregar OAuth a una solicitud de API?

Tags: python, oauth2

Quiero acceder a mi lista de amigos en goodreads usando la API y en particular la URI [descrita aquí](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#user.friends):

```
https://www.goodreads.com/friend/user/49393496?format=xml
```

Pero me devuelve `not authorized`. Si agrego mi clave:

```
https://www.goodreads.com/friend/user/49393496?format=xml&key=my-key
```

aparece un mensaje "no autorizado". Segun [este forum](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/2360666-user-friends-issue?comment=119055000) parece que la solución está llamando a esto

```
https://www.goodreads.com/friend/user?id=6837622&format=xml&key=pU8aWDMPyBMZ45ObUtZyg
```

Y a través de oauth. Más precisamente parece que es necesario agregar encabezados OAuth. Obviamente, uno tiene que asegurarse de tener los parámetros como parte del contenido firmado.

Por consiguiente, **¿cómo añadir OAuth a una consulta de una API?** Soy un gran principiante con OAuth.

Utilizo Python para obtener los resultados.

#### Actualización

Para conocer cuales son mis amigos sobre Goodreads trato llamando a esto a través de oauth. Es decir de identificarme con OAuth utilizando el siguiente codigo [que proviene de levex.org](http://www.lexev.org/en/2015/oauth-step-step/):

```
"""
Example of OAuth 2.0 process with client-side only web page.
We can access to user's resources without providing a client_secret!
Given access_token will be short-lived, about 1 or 2 hours, whereas
access_token given by server-side workflow is long-lived, up to 60 days.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067947/facebook-access-token-server-side-vs-client-side-flows
API of facebook is used: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow
"""
import webbrowser
import urllib
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode
#from urlparse import parse_qsl, urlparse
import random

CLIENT_KEY = 'your_app_key'
CLIENT_SECRET = None  # Not needed here!

AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth'
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token'
API_RESOURCE_URL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me'

# host must be set explicitly in facebook app configuration, otherwise forbidden
CALLBACK_URL = "http://rrhosterer.com:8000/oauth2"

###########################################
# STEP 1: user cofirmation and access_token
###########################################

auth_params = {
    "client_id": CLIENT_KEY,
    "state": str(random.getrandbits(64)),  # to protect from CSRF
    "redirect_uri": CALLBACK_URL,
    "response_type": "token",  # note the response_type here
    "scope": "email",  # we want to get access to email
}

url = "?".join([AUTHORIZE_URL, urlencode(auth_params)])
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
redirected_url = raw_input("Paste here url you were redirected:\n")
# Note, that redirected_url will contain parameters after #
redirected_url = redirected_url.replace('oauth2?#', 'oauth2?')
redirect_params = dict(parse_qsl(urlparse(redirected_url).query))
assert redirect_params['state'] == auth_params['state']  # protect CSRF
access_token = redirect_params['access_token']

####################################
# STEP 2: request to server resource
####################################
api_params = {
    'access_token': access_token,
}
url = "?".join([API_RESOURCE_URL, urlencode(api_params)])
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
assert resp.code == 200
resp_content = json.loads(resp.read())
email = resp_content['email']
print("Email:", email)
```

Sin embargo parece que necesita crear una aplicación de Facebook. Parece muy complicado para simplemente buscar a sus amigos en este sitio.

Comment: Hola, debes imolementar una solución en tu programa de tal manera que puedas manejar las credenciales que proporciona OAuth. No es tan sencillo como realizar una solicitud `http` y listo. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias. Conoces referencias para manejar las credenciales que proporciona OAuth ? Soy nuevo en este campo

Comment: No programo en Python, pero seguro encontrarás referencias en la web sobre el tema. Dale un vistazo a este [post](http://www.lexev.org/en/2015/oauth-step-step/). Es algo antiguo (2015), pero puede ser de utilidad para ver una implementación. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

OAuth ofrece distintas concesiones (grants) o flujos (flows) para authenticar  aplicaciones cliente o usuarios.

Haciendo una lectura rápida de la documentación del API de Goodreads, parece que solo ofrece la posibilidad de utilizar el Authorization Code grant de OAuth. Este flujo sirve para autenticar usuarios que se concectan a través de un navegador desde un cliente no confidencial.

Parece que tú lo que quiers hacer es un simple script que accede a tus datos en Goodreads. Para eso necesitarías Client Credentials grant, utilizada para autenticar clientes confidenciales, no usuarios. Parece que Goodreads no ofree esta posibilidad.

En definitiva, las posibilidades de integración que ofrce Goodreads están orientadas al desarrollo de aplicaciones web que interactuan con sus usuarios no a scripts que actúan como cliente.

Esto no quiere decir que no puedas hacer lo que deseas, simplemente, que tal y cmo ya has avanzado, necesitas:

1. Crear una aplicación web
2. Registrar la aplicación web en Goodreads (tienes que indicar las URL de callback para el Authorization Code grant)
3. Goodreads te proporcionará algo parecido a un `client_id` y `client_secret` que identificará tu aplicación web.

Una vez tengas desplegada tu aplicación el flujo se paracerá a lago parecido aesto:

1. Te conectarías a tu aplicación web y pedirás authenticarte con tu login en good reads.
2. Tu aplicación redireccionará a le servidor the autorización de Goodreads
3. Goodreads verificará que llega un inicio de autenticación desde un servidor conocido con identificador de cliente conocido y te pedirá tus credenciales de usuario en Goodreads con un formulario
4. Introducirás tus credencials
5. Goodreads valida tus credenciales y si son correctas redireccionará al navegador de vuelta a tu aplicación web (url de callback) junto con un `code`.
6. Tu aplicación web intercamabiará con el servidor de autenticación de Goodreads el `code` por una `access_token`
7. Con el `access_token` tu aplicación podrá acceder a los recursos de tu usuario en Goodreads.

Si quieres hacer esto sin necesidad de publicar una aplicación web en un servidor, puedes utilizar un servicio como Ngrok para registrar una URL de callback que apunte a un script de python que se esté ejecutando en tu PC.
6.